# LicenseException in my C# code

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm adding licence checking for my WCF component, and i found LicenseException in System.ComponentModel namespace.
Am i free to use this exception class in case when user enters invalid licence key, or it will be better to create my own?

Really i want to find an answer for more general question. Is it safe to throw any type of exception that i can find in .NET for example ExecutionEngineException seems pretty internal stuff.

```
if (!LicenceHelper.CheckLicence())
    throw new ApplicationException("Invalid Serial Key or Activation Key");
    throw new LicenseException(typeof(DataProvider));
```

Which line of code is better second of third?

Comment: I would avoid throwing "ExecutionEngineException". As another developer on the project, if I encountered that, my first thought would be "Holy crap I broke the CLR" since that's generally what that exception is reserved for.

Comment: First one rocks. Or even better, just throw `Exception`.

Comment: btw: I would check for a very good security because license systems in .NET are in most cases very easy to crack.

Comment: throw new LicEx("Your key expired " +date +" you need to call Joe at 1-800-" +phoneNumberFromConfigOrLicenseFile + " to buy a new one"); I mean, the point of this exception is to sell a license, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would go for option 3, write your own custom exception and throw that.

```
class InvalidSerialException : ApplicationException
{
    public InvalidSerialException() :
        base("Invalid Serial Key or Activation Key")
    {
    }

    public InvalidSerialException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }

    public InvalidSerialException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }

    protected InvalidSerialException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {
    }
}



//elsewhere
if (!LicenceHelper.CheckLicence())
    throw new InvalidSerialException());
```

This gives you more flexibility, for example if you wanted to include the attempted serial key in the payload of the exception it is possible with a custom exception but not as easy to do with the two exceptions built in to .NET. Also it makes it easier to catch exactly the exception you want in your calling methods instead of just hoping that the `ApplicationException` you are catching is the `ApplicationException` you wanted to catch.